# downgrading to rails 3.2.18 from 4.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am wondering if someone could give me some advice. I am looking to help someone out with an app thats in Rails 3 and everything i have done has been with Rails 4. How do i go about setting myself up to work on this without disrupting all my rails 4 work?

the versions required for the project are as follows:
Ruby version 1.9.3-p448
Rails version 3.2.18

The versions on my mac are 
Ruby version ruby 2.1.1p76
Rails version 4.1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is to [install RVM](https://rvm.io/) and install Ruby 1.9.3 on your machine. Create a gemset specific for the app you want to work with.

When you finish to work on that app, simply drop the gemset and your existing configuration will not be affected.

Comment: So with RVM could i install two different ruby version on my machine so that over the coming weeks i could work on this and my old work?

Comment: Yes, correct. You can install several different Ruby versions, switch from one to other on the fly. And each version can have its own gemsets.

Comment: When you said drop the gemset do you literally mean the gemfile specifications?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to RVM, you can use [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv), which is recommended by rails:

> We recommend managing your Ruby installation through rbenv. It’s an
>   easy way to run multiple versions for different applications and
>   update when a new release is made.

source: http://rubyonrails.org/download/